# Why didn't the Eternian Army help, or even offer any aid, to Etheria against the Horde?

Tags: he-man, masters-of-the-universe, she-ra

Thinking back on it now, it makes little sense; Adora was the *Princess* of Eternia, the kingdom if not the *planet* itself.  And in various flashbacks, the Sorceress says that the Horde *tried* to invade Eternia as they had countless other planets, but "they were no match for your father's brave soldiers, and the magic of Castle Greyskull". You can see it here:

Hordack *himself* even says "You may have defeated us, but you'll never see *this* child again!" when he escapes to Etheria, and later in the *Secret of the Sword* film says "The Horde has *no more interest* in this world!" [likely because they got their *asses* handed to them!]

Considering the Horde is purported to be a galaxy-spanning empire, Eternia must be **one TOUGH ass planet of Badasses** to have them just straight "Nope!" off the planet and **never** return!

But then.... ***why* didn't the Eternian Army come to aid *their* Princess in a rebellion she was a part of for *years?***

I mean obvious separation of the series aside.... wouldn't *that* have ended the war *sooner?*

Think about it:

- The Eternian Army---- not even the PLANET-wide army, just (it seems) those under King Randor---- were *more* than a match for the Horde. So they had an established success against the evil forces already.
- Even if they wouldn't have Grayskull's magic on their side this time, they would *still* have the Crystal castle, or *at least* the Kingdoms of Bright Moon and its allies like Spike-Heart. So magically, they should be covered.
- They had adequate *reason* to join the fight, as the Horde **had kept their Princess as a POW for *at least* 18 years!** Even if they want to claim that a whole other planet is somewhat "out of their jurisdiction," as a foreign power, they *can* offer aid to a friendly kingdom under siege from a common enemy. Adora's imprisonment, as a War Crime, would be justification enough for them sending troops or supplies as aid to the Etherian realms as a means of support. Not only would they be protecting their interest (Adora) they could argue being "pulled" into the conflict due to "previous aggressive actions against the kingdom of Eternia" by the Horde.

And its not as if they were engaged in any other serious conflict; Skeletor *was* a continuous threat, yes,but not one the army is called in to do with. His villainous band is more of a "Terrorist cell" trying to make incursions into the kingdom, not on the same scale as full other nation waging endless battle. Sending troops to aid the Rebellion as a means of assuring Adora's safety seems logical.

And yeah, the Rebellion was going on for *years,* even if we presume it only *started* a few months back before or right at the beginning of **Secret of the Sword.** This to makes sense, as by that time Angella had been captured, Adora had been raised on the planet as a trained and established Force Captain, and a good portion of Etheria had been under Horde rule and taxation for years. This had been made worse by an apparent "time skip" that had occurred between seasons 1 and 2, a time skip made clear by the life of General Sundar.

The Rebellion ran into Sundar in season 1, and they'd been fighting alongside She-Ra for some time by then. Adora had been with the Rebellion as one of their co-leaders after *Secret* in season 1, *before* Sundar had switched sides; when Sundar returned in season 2, Adora was almost *Completely* in charge of the Rebellion by then, and Sundar and Mally had a daughter who was *at least* 3 or 4 years old. If the war had been continuing through **All** that time, then that's *most likely* 5 years of battle with the Horde!

Granted, time probably moves differently on Eternia and Etheria, but it's still a long period for a Princess to be at risk and a king of a relatively peaceful nation to *not* offer any support.

I know there was a post-2000s comic which *may* have gone into details [have no clue, honestly], but is there any canon reason why no *suggestion* of aid was given?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've seen those, but wasn't portal between worlds erratic or even permanently closed by the end of the cross-over movie?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Not at all! In fact, it was used _multiple times_ to pull He-Man over to give She-Ra some aid. Those portals went _through_ castle Greyskull, though, and usually only sent a few people at a time. However, there was nothing that said the sorceress _Couldn't_ open a bigger gate to send a few Eternian battalions through.

Comment: The Etheria of the early Horde comic books is not the same as the Etheria of She-ra.  Etheria portals were considered erratic originally - but not in the filmation universe.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Okay, viable.... but then, after it was shown **in cartoon** that stable portals could be made basically at whim (remember, the Sorceress said "should you ever wish to return, just call me through the sword,") ... why didn't that become a viable option at _that_ point?

Answer (score 1):

No aid is probably not accurate.  Covert aid is suggested as there were a few episodes with He-man and Orko helping on Etheria. In-universe perhaps a covert resistance was preferred over actual war because the Horde was merely being oppressive at that point.

Comment: Hmmm... i agree that He-Man assited the Rebellion on _numerous_ occasions, but they were _still_ fighting to **Free** Etheria from the Horde's Cluthes.  you do make a point in so much that, by the end of season 1, it was more of a "standstill battle" than a constant war; many kingdoms, including Brightmoon, more or less went about their business, and it was other Horde-occupied spaces (Thamore village, Beast Island or the badlands), which were under constant horde rule. But again, if an Eternian force could drive the horde off world once...why not just do it again, especially to protect Adora?

Comment: Well as I recall there was a point where King Randor was so furious with Skeletor he was going to wipe Snake Mountain off the map and then backed off.  In-universe they seem to prefer containment over decisive victory.

Comment: Again, you make a point...but I think it had more to do with the immediate severity of the _threat,_  than "containment." Skeletor could be likened to a dangerous Crime Lord or Mafia boss; yes, a constant, ever present threat, but he doesn't _literally_ own the city or people. Given relative scale, they could be left to the Police. Da _Horde_ by contrast, are a **major invasion/occupation force,** like unto the Nazi Army in WWII. If America = Eternia, and Etheria= Europe, then the equivalent action would be sending _Battalions,_ not a Police force, into the fray to _stop_ the actual _warring._

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, regarding your statement, I do not believe time runs differently between Eternia and Etheria, at least per the Filmation series continuity.  I will stick with the Filmation continuity as that is the most well known.

The likely answer here is probably a combination of factors, but mostly (1) offensive capabilities, (2) resources, and (3) accessibility.

You state that the Eternian guard was able to defend Eternia from the Horde. This event takes place in Eternia, which means the Eternians were defending.  If they took the battle to the Horde on Etheria, the Horde would be on the defense and the army roles would be switched.  Perhaps Eternians are better at defense than offense; consider the majority of the rest of Eternia is presented as a wild land of crazy untamed mystical chaos, and divided fiefdoms which do not necessarily bow to King Randor.  If the Eternians were capable offensively, they'd have a better handle on their own home turf, but they do not.  This demonstrates they are better at defense than offense.

Consider that on Eternia the entire army was available; Randor needs to also maintain Eternia while fighting a war in another dimension; he could not possibly send his entire army on an offensive mission to Etheria while simultaneously defending Eternia.

Regarding accessibility, Etheria is another planet/dimension/galaxy; one that isn't accessed till the movie special, and afterwards this access isn't overly abused, meaning it may require special circumstances. Perhaps the resources needed to move an army to the dimension of Etheria (and eventually back), including ongoing supplies, is not a viable proposition.

These are three rationale examples why Randor might not have sent his army.

Comment: Interesting Argument! I may need to post multiple replies to cover all of them, but here goes:
1.The time theory is speculative. We don;t really see characters "grow" in either show, but _Sundar's family_mis a big indicator that **a lot** of time has passed on Etheria. Adora swore to her parents she wouldn't come back to Eternia _until_ Etheria was freed. but it's hard to think Randor would go **years** without seeing his daughter/knowing she's in danger, even for a good cause, and do _nothing_ to help her in any significant way. Hence why time may be "perceived" differently on the two worlds

Comment: Adam and Adora are twins. If time passed differently between dimensions, Adora would be presented as significantly older than Adam. Your focus on Sundar's family is noted - perhaps the simplest answer is correct: lot of time passes between the two episodes in question.

Comment: 2. You may have a point about Eternia's stronger defense than offense. While both planets are full of magic, Lou Schieffer wanted Eteria to be more rugged and dangerous to fit with He-man's aesthetic; Etheria, by contrast, was more a land of beauty and wonder. He-Man also had a more "sci-fi" feel, which is why there was so much "tech being used wisely" in his adventures; it made a _lot_ of Eternia able to be accessed. She-Ra's were more about _magic._ So while the Eter-army would lose the planets natural protection, they'd still have advantages in numbers, tactics, and with Duncan's hardware.

Comment: Yes, Adam and Adora are twins, but i'm speaking more here of _length of years_ than actual _aging_. And keep in mind that Adora is a half human **Eternian born;** she wouldn't necessarily be affected the same way other Etherian's are. you ever notice how more _naturally agile_ she is than even other _trained_ Etherians, even without her powers? That _could_ be down to her past horde training, but seems like natural gifts. Also, Etheria is another **planet** somehwere outside of Eternian space (which is said to be at the very _center_ of the universe); its never said to be another "Dimension".

Comment: You are right that Randor couldn't and likely _wouldn't_ send his **entire** army and leave his planet defenseless; _no_ good king would! But earlier I compared Etheria to Europe and Eternia to the US with the Horde as the Nazis. Using that logic, Troops _were_ kept in the states and its Providences to defend our spaces, but literally **thousands** of soldiers were sent to aid Europe during WWII. Taking for granted that Randor's kingdom isn't as big as the US, he _still_ could link with other Eternian kingdoms as "Allies" (like Avian, or Andros) and send some battalions over that 5 year period

Comment: I may be conflating the modern She-Ra Etheria with legacy Etheria.

Comment: Legacy Etheria? you mean the one in the new Netflix series?

Comment: Modern is Netflix; Legacy would be Filmation.

Comment: Well, i heard Etheria on the Netflix show _is_ in a different dimension. From what I recall, "Legacy", though, Etheria was just a different _planet_ within the same _space_ ; the same laws of physics seem to apply. This is opposed to the various other dimensions we have seen in both series ( Trolla, the Dark One's realm, the 6th dimension in _Three Courageous Hearts,_ the void where Orko lost He-man's sword, to name a few). Supposedly both planets inhabit our "space", they are just in other galaxies.